# Volume function keys are recognized but don't change the volume

Tags: keyboard, pulseaudio, mate-desktop

I'm running Jessie with MATE. The volume keys themselves are functional but they don't change the volume, and while I can use the volume control widget it's inconvenient. My problem is similar to [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/regaining-usage-of-volume-control-media-keys-after-removing-pulseaudio) except I have `pulseaudio` installed.

Now, I did delete pulseaudio at one point, but I later reinstalled it, so I don't know how to fix this. I believe it installed packages to replace pulseaudio when I deleted it and maybe there's a conflict? The keys themselves work and are correctly mapped in my keyboard shortcuts. The megaphone icon thing appears on the screen when I press the volume keys, but the volume won't change.

`xev` output: (mute/volume up/volume down all return the same thing)

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

`#1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2`

Comment: The issue you linked to was likely caused by removal of gnome packages related to pulseaudio, not by removal of pulseaudio itself. Do you get ACPI events or X events for your volume keys (run `xev`, move mouse cursor into window, press keys)? If it's the latter, you need to somehow configure mate to react to the X events.

Comment: Do the keys work if you create a new user and log in using that?

Comment: I confirm they don't.

Comment: What does `dpkg --get-selections | grep mate | grep pulse` list? There are a couple of MATE pulseaudio packages in the repository. Not running MATE myself, but from the description `mate-settings-daemon-pulse` might be important. (If anyone actually knows, please don't let this comment prevent you from posting an answer!)

Comment: @derobert mate-media-pulse    install

Comment: but I'm unable to locate that package...

Comment: It's in stable (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mate-settings-daemon-pulse) ... does `apt-cache policy mate-settings-daemon-pulse` show it?

Comment: mate-settings-daemon-pulse:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.2-4
  Version table:
     1.8.2-4 0
        990 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages

Comment: I installed mate-settings-daemon-pulse. it replaced mate-settings-daemon-gstreamer. volume still not working

Comment: Recommended read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Extra_keyboard_keys

Comment: My keys are properly mapped

Comment: control if `acpi-support` is on your system.

Comment: it's installed. crap my bounty is ending.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's seriously annoying me 6 years later. :)